# MongoDB Java Driver: Convert BsonDocument to Document and back

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the MongoDB Java Driver for my project to access my database from Java.

I usually use `Document` as it's quite easy to use and all methods in `MongoDBCollection`, such as `find()` work with it and return `Document` instances.

However, in some cases I want to use the equivalent `BsonDocument` which is more verbose but offers type-safety by implementing `Map<String,BsonValue>`, which `Document` does not have because it implements `Map<String,Object>`.

I am able to convert a **`Document` into a `BsonDocument`** with this:

```
BsonDocument bsonDoc = document.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
```

The problem here is, that all methods in `MongoDBCollection`, like `insertOne()` only take `Document` instances, so I can not use these.

---

For me, it looks like there are 2 ways to solve this problem:

If the `BsonDocument` created by `toBsonDocument()` is in some way backed by the orginal `Document`, I could use the original `Document` instance even when I  made modifications to the `BsonDocument`, because the original `Document` would reflect these changes, right?
Does it work this way or is the `BsonDocument` just a copy?

The second way would be to convert from **`BsonDocument` back to `Document`**. Is this in some way possible?

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using any ORM? If not please check Morphia:https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/, no need to change to and fro from BsonDocument

Comment: have you tried passing BsonDocument to the insertOne() ? It should work.

Comment: @dkb thanks! I will look into that! Maybe that will make the whole thing easier.

Comment: @Veeram With your comment I was able to find out that there is another `getCollection` I can use to get other types of documents in the collection instance. I will look into this and see if I can get it to work!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have an instance of `CodecRegistry`, you can convert `BsonDocument` to `Document` and vice-versa using this adapter:

```java
public class DocumentAdapter {
    private final CodecRegistry registry;
    private final Codec<Document> codec;

    public DocumentAdapter(CodecRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.codec = registry.get(Document.class);
    }

    public Document fromBson(BsonDocument bson) {
        return codec.decode(bson.asBsonReader(), DecoderContext.builder().build());
    }

    public BsonDocument toBson(Document document) {
        return document.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, registry);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great.  I took a peak at DocumentCodec and it looks like `decode()` is also threadsafe!

Comment: You can get a codec registry via https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html#getCodecRegistry()

Answer (score 4):

```
public static Document bsonToDocument(BsonDocument bsonDocument) {
    DocumentCodec codec = new DocumentCodec();
    DecoderContext decoderContext = DecoderContext.builder().build();
    return codec.decode(new BsonDocumentReader(bsonDocument), decoderContext);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this "workaround" of converting the `BsonDocument` to string and then the string to `Document`.
Might be useful depending the scenario.

```java
final BsonDocument json = BsonDocument.parse("{}");
final Document parsedJson = Document.parse(json.toJson());
```

or simply

```java
final Document json = Document.parse(BsonDocument.parse("{}").toJson());
```